# Nuch 2.2.1 Hbase 0.90.4 ClassNotFoundException bug

Tags: java, hbase, web-crawler, classnotfoundexception, nutch

Hi all Iam facing a big problem to set my first crawling using Nutch 2.2.1 and Hbase 0.90.4 It seems that nutch is buggy. nothing is working at all. please help me.

I downloaded Nutch 2.2.1 and Hbase 0.90.4 from apache and made changes on configuration files before compile. i uncommented the gora-core and gora-hbase in ivy.xml to this one

```
<dependency org="org.apache.gora" name="gora-hbase" rev="0.2" conf="*->default" />
<dependency org="org.apache.gora" name="gora-core" rev="0.2" conf="*->default"/>
```

after doing all stuff i run:

```
bin/nutch inject urls/seed.txt
```

and i got Exception trace

```
InjectorJob: starting at 2014-10-03 12:58:16
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: urls/seed.txt
InjectorJob: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.getDataStoreClass(StorageUtils.java:89)
at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:73)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:221)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)
```

I changed the rev version to 0.3 for both gora-core and gora-hbase but i got the same error. As it seem that nutch couldn't find HBaseStore i put the gora-hbase jar into the CLASSPATH but still got the same error.

Iam using ubuntu 12

Answer (score 0):

I tried to crawl websites with Hadoop & Nutch and I got the same error. When I checked my ivy/ivy.xml I saw missing dependency

`<dependency org="org.apache.gora" name="gora-hbase" rev="0.2" conf="*->default" />`

When I uncomment it, run ant clean and ant runtime, bug disapper. I am using Ubuntu 12 server too.

Comment: my gora setting with rev="0.3" is already enabled but still doesnt fix the problem